# I don't know where I'm going wrong in calculating the expected replacement cost

Tags: probability, statistics, risk-assessment

This is the question: Suppose the probability a plant is destroyed in year 1 is 2% and the probability a plant is destroyed in year 2 assuming it was not destroyed previously is 4%. When the plant is destroyed, it would cost $147782 to replace. Assumed the interest rate is 5%, what is the expected replacement cost, round to nearest dollar?

I've tried the summation of y1 expected value and y2 expected value, then for each year at a 5% discount, my work is shown below:

[image]

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you only interested in the costs of repair over the first $2$ years?  Are you looking for the Present Value of those expected costs? Assuming you are indeed after the Present Value, how should we read the $5\%$ interest rate?  Is that an annual number?  Semi-annual?  Something else?

Comment: Are we to assume that the repair costs (if any) come due at the end of the relevant year?  Something else?

Comment: The replacement cost would be dependent on if the plant is destroyed.  So if the probability of a destroyed plant is 2% then the probability it's not destroyed is 98%. I'm assuming the 5% is annual... but uncertain

Comment: Well, maybe you guessed wrong on the nature of the $5\%$.  It also makes a big difference *when* in the year the repair costs are expected (assuming there are some).  Since the problem requests an answer within a single dollar, all these assumptions are crucial.

Comment: Should also say:  it is odd that the repair costs are fixed.  Surely these should grow at the riskless rate, right?  For a problem expecting a very precise answer, it is very vaguely written.

Comment: As I stated, I do not know what I am doing wrong, so I could very well be inaccurate about the 5%.  I was given that question, but uncertain on the steps I need to take to formulate a correct answer.

Comment: We can't guess at the missing details for you.  I suggest seeking clarification from whomever set the problem.

Comment: What details do you think are missing?

Comment: I believe I have stated my biggest questions already.

Comment: Could you possibly inbox me? I don't know how to do so.

Comment: I don't know what that means.